# Ruby gsub! change everything

Tags: ruby, gsub

in Ruby I have this situation

```
monurl = mon[0][1]['externallinks'][0]
nowlm = mon[0][1]['externallinks'][0]
```

with

```
mon[0][1]['externallinks'][0] = 'abc'
```

If I do

```
monurl.gsub!('a', 'z')
```

`monurl` is changed, but also `mon[0][1]['externallinks'][0]` and `nowlm` because of Ruby object management.

Is there a way to change only `monurl` and not `mon[0][1]['externallinks'][0]` and `nowlm`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have two variables referring to the very same object, a string. If you modify that string via `gsub!`, the change will of course be reflected by both variables, since both of them still refer to that object.

Comment: Note that in ruby / rails, methods that end in `!` (`gsub!`, `sort!`, etc.) are marked as 'dangerous' in some way. To find out what the 'danger' is, you'll have to read the docs for that method.

Answer (score 4):

```rb
monurl = monurl.gsub('a', 'z')
```

This changes `monurl`, but leaves `nowlm` and `mon[0][1]['externallinks'][0]` unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

If you want `monurl` to manage its own copy of the string from the start, just let it refer to a copy of the string, and not to the original:

```
monurl = mon[0][1]['externallinks'][0].dup
```